# Telerik Reporting - Picturebox is already in use error

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a following exception on my report:
[image: Object in use]

I think i tried every possible way to fix it, I even changed the way I load that image to load it from base64 string:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(@"base64string");
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
   pbLogo.Value = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

The problem is that it's non deterministic - sometimes it will work and sometines and will only appear from time to time, without any way to always reproduce it.

Edit - this is a designer code:

```
        // pbLogo
        // 
        this.pbLogo = new Telerik.Reporting.PictureBox()
        this.pbLogo.Location = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PointU(Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(0D), Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Inch(3.9418537198798731E-05D));
        this.pbLogo.MimeType = "";
        this.pbLogo.Name = "pbLogo";
        this.pbLogo.Size = new Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.SizeU(Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Pixel(185D), Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Pixel(42D));
        this.pbLogo.Sizing = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.ImageSizeMode.ScaleProportional;
        this.pbLogo.Style.BackgroundImage.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
        this.pbLogo.Style.BackgroundImage.Repeat = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.BackgroundRepeat.NoRepeat;
        this.pbLogo.Value = "";
```

Comment: Where you call `Graphics` object? The corresponding object should be disposed before setting `Image` property of the `PictureBox`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - i added a code from the designer code behind

Comment: Your provided example still not showing how the image being created (I assumed you're using `Bitmap` object). Which line of code exactly throwing that error?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - this is it - there is no more code.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto any idea, about what could be the cause of that error?